# Shortest Path: Picking up cards without duplicates

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

I have a homework question in my algorithms class that asks the following:

> You have a game board and a path to the end. You move one step at a
>   time. At each 'position' you step to there is a stack of cards (a
>   subset of the standard 52 card deck). There could be 1 card, 2 cards,
>   3 cards, etc. No duplicates, and there is at least one card.
>
> The purpose of the game is to pick a card at each position. **You
>   cannot select the same card twice**. By the time you reach the end,
>   you want the total face value of the cards to be minimal.
>
> Devise an algorithm that, given how many positions there are, and what set of    cards are at each position, find the minimal combination of cards to pick up.

I don't really know where to start. I could do an exhaustive search but I fear that would not be efficient enough. I know that it's not as simple as just picking the smallest card at each position. Since you cannot pick the same card twice, you might encounter a situation where it's optimal to pick a slightly higher value card initially, then the much cheaper one at a later stage. I considered creating a 'decision tree', but that wouldn't help with time complexity either.

Comment: Dijkstra's algorithm?

Comment: It seems to me that Dijkstra doesn't apply here. I wanted to create a graph where each vertex/node is a unique position AND card choice. For example, a vertex could be something like "Position 5, Queen of Spades". However, this would essentially form a tree, which means Dijkstra's algorithm would no longer be very efficient.

Comment: Min-cost matching?

Comment: Does the graph have more than one possible path? Or is the freedom only in the choice of cards and not in the choice of path?

Comment: The path is already determined.

Comment: Is there an upper bound on path length? The only solution I think is to use back-tracking, however this could be computationally expensive if the path length is close to 52

Comment: Is it allowed to pick hearts 4 and diamonds 4? Meaning: they are considered different cards, but they have the same face value?

Comment: What are the values for the cards Jack, Queen, and King? 11, 12, 13? And Ace = 1?

Comment: Doesn't say. I would assume Ace = 1, J = 11, Q = 12, K = 13

Answer (score 0):

Use backtracking to find all possible paths, and then choose the path that yields the minimum value.

You can pre-process the data with two (possibly more) rules:

If one stack of cards in the path has a card that no other stack has, you can reduce the cards in that stack to the unique card.

If any stack in the path has only one card, you can remove all similar cards from other stacks.

You're still looking at a worst case of roughly 52! if the path is very long.

Comment: The path lengths seem to be in the 1-20 range. But 52! / 20! is still quite a large number.

Comment: 52!/(52-20)! but yes, the number is still far too large to compute with arbitrary card stacks

Comment: If you don't need an absolutely minimal value you could consider a meta-heuristic like PSO or genetic algorithms

Comment: Afraid we haven't done heuristic algorithms. Just the absolute basics so far (searching, sorting, graphs, shortest paths). I believe we need a precise answer as well. (As in, the absolute minimal answer).

Comment: It seems as though we're missing information. Or perhaps the instructor mis-calculated the complexity of the problem. Any exhaustive search is going to cost at least (numberOfSteps)! to compute.

Answer (score 0):

After looking into this for quite a while, I have not found an algorithm that has a worst case time complexity that is better than *O(s!)* where *s* is the number of stacks. For the pure theorist the problem can be solved in constant time as the number of cards and stacks has an upper limit. It is just a very ... big constant. The big-O notation only makes sense if your input size has no upper limit (we could achieve that requirement if we would allow the use of a custom card set, where the face value could go from *1..n*, where *n* is variable).

Still I would like to pass on some thoughts that can help write an algorithm that performs well in many (but not all) configurations:

#### Definitions

- A card's *id* is the combination of rank (1..13) and suit (clubs, hearts, diamonds, spades). Rank 0 = Ace of clubs, rank 1 = Ace of Hearts, ... rank 4 = Two of clubs, ... rank 7 = Two of Spades, ... rank 51 = King of Spades, the last one.
- ***s*** is the number of stacks
- ***n<sub>i</sub>*** is the number of cards on stack number *i*.

#### Algorithm

1. Mark all cards with the number of the stack they are in;
2. Sort the cards on each stack by increasing *id* (so with the lowest *id* at the top of the stack), and also create a map (by *id*) so the position of a cards in the sorted stack can be quickly found by its *id*.
3. Create a another list which has all cards together, also sorted by increasing *id*. Also create buckets by *id* for this overall sorted list, to allow direct lookup by *id*. As cards are not unique across stacks there can be duplicate *id* values.
4. **Clean-up 1:** For every stack *i* with *n<sub>i</sub> > s*: remove *n<sub>i</sub> - s* cards from the bottom of that stack so that the resulting stack size is at most *s*. This is because there is no way such a card could be part of an optimal solution. There are at most *s-1* duplicates in that stack, so the first non-duplicate card will be at position <=*s* in the sort order of that stack. Whichever way you pick cards from the other stacks, at least one of the first *s* cards can be picked from this stack. There is no reason to take a card further towards the bottom of that stack. So they can be removed. Make sure to replicate the removal of cards in the overall list of step 3. After this step there are at most *s²* cards in the configuration.
5. **Clean-up 2:** Go through the sorted list of all cards: whenever a unique *id* *X* is found (i.e. it is alone in its bucket), get the stack number of that card *X*, and remove from that stack any card below card *X*. There is no way that these removed cards contribute to an optimal solution. Imagine such a card would be picked: it could be replaced by the unique card *X* and provide an equal or better solution (i.e. lower sum of ranks). Make sure to replicate the removal of cards in the overall list of step 3. This step could make some cards unique that were not unique before. As this step progresses through all the cards in order, these newly-become-unique cards will be treated in the same way. Once this step is completed we have stacks that have all their cards being duplicate with a card in another stack, except for maybe one card, which then is the card at the bottom of the stack.
6. Now we can pick a card.

   - If there is a stack with no card then this branch in the search tree offered no solution. Backtrack as we should have picked a card from this stack earlier on.
   - If there is a stack with just one card, pick that card.
   - Otherwise: It is clear that picking a card with minimal *id* (i.e. at the start of the overall sorted list), will lead to an optimal solution. Imagine you would create a solution without picking a card with this minimal *id*, then you would have taken another card from the stack(s) which have these minimal *id* cards. But then you could simply improve the solution by replacing one of these picked cards by one of the minimal *id* cards (in the same stack). If there is only one such minimal *id* card, take that one. Otherwise the algorithm has to branch of in as many branches as there are duplicates of this minimal *id* card. This represents a node in the typical search tree this algorithm has to walk through.

   As you pick a card, remove all other cards of that stack (applying the change to the overal list as well), and the stack itself, thereby reducing the value *s* with 1.
7. If at this point *s* is 0, then we have a "solution", but maybe not the best one. If it is better than the one we had so far, register this as the best solution. Backtrack in order to visit other branches in the search tree, which might still have better solutions. If, on the other hand, *s* > 0, repeat from step 4 onwards (with this decreased *s*).

   Note that when backtracking (in steps 6 or 7), you need also to restore the data structure (removed cards should be added again to the stacks and in the overall list in their sorted position).

The above algorithm still performs bad when you have a lot of duplicates.

#### Prune branches in search tree

If you would have a way to find a lower-bound of the value-sum you can potentially reach in the current branch of the search tree, then you could benefit from this knowledge and sometimes backtrack at an earlier stage (i.e. "prune" a branch): as soon as this lower bound is equal or higher than the best solution found so far, there is no use in continuing the search in that branch; it can never lead to a better solution. The better (i.e. higher) you can set this lower bound, the better performance the algorithm will have.

Here are a few ideas for calculating a lower bound for the sum:

First of all, this lower-bound sum would obviously include the sum of the card ranks that have already been taken at this point in the search. To this the minimum values should be added of the cards that still need to be picked. I suggest two ways to do that:

1. Add the ranks of the cards at the tops of the remaining stacks. Some of these values could belong to duplicate cards, and so they might not actually contribute to the solution, but a true solution would have values which are equal or greater than these values. So this sum will represent a lower bound.
2. Alternatively, you could identify the *s* lowest and **distinct** *id* values that are still available in the overall sorted list, and take the sum of those. Any lower sum than that would have to use duplicates, which is not allowed, so this represents a lower bound. On the other hand an actual solution might have a greater sum, because this lower bound might have counted values which were on the same stack, which is not allowed either.

The calculation should be done incrementally, i.e. one should avoid to have to calculate it from scratch again and again. Instead, as each step in the algorithm is performed and cards are removed/picked, this lower-bound should be adapted accordingly, which will be more efficient.

A smarter combination of the two above methods could be used. However, the smarter you make it, the more time it will take to calculate it, and the algorithm might or might not get a performance improvement because of it.

So far my conclusions. The most difficult configurations have many duplicates. For instance a configuration with 52 stacks, where all stacks have almost all cards (just a few cards taken out here and there), will be difficult to solve quickly.